# limit of intersection of events

Tags: probability, limits, statistics

$A_{n}, B_{n}, C_{n}$ are sequences of events, $A_{n}$ and $B_{n}$ are independent for each $n$, given $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(A_{n}) = \frac{1}{3} $$ $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(B_{n}) = \frac{1}{2} $$ and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(C_{n}) = 1 $$ compute $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(A_{n} \cap B_{n} \cap C_{n}).$$

I assume the answer is just simply $\frac{1}{6}$, but I can not think of any theorem to prove this, please help

Comment: Don't think this really constitutes an answer, but on page 8 of All of Statistics it is presented as a definition. That is, if a set of events is independent, then any (finite) arbitrary intersection is equal to the product of the probability of each event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb P(A_n\cap B_n\cap C_n)+\mathbb P(A_n\cap B_n\cap C_n^c)=\mathbb P(A_n\cap B_n)=\mathbb P(A_n)\mathbb P(B_n)\to\frac16.$$
And $A_n\cap B_n\cap C_n^c\subseteq C_n^c$, so
$$
0\leq \mathbb P(A_n\cap B_n\cap C_n^c) \leq \mathbb P(C_n^c)=1-\mathbb P(C_n) \to 0.
$$

Comment: this solution looks perfect!